Asset prefix not working - can I write a script to locate and change the bundle.js?
What's happening is when I run the build step for my next.js project the assetPrefix and the basePath are not being applied to some files. Specifically the bundled .json for each path and another random set of media files.
I'm using  Next.js 15.0.2, Webpack to bundle, nothing out of the ordinary.
The example is of my local build config:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
   output: 'export', 
   assetPrefix: '/custom.com/wp-content/themes/custom/out',
   basePath: "/custom.com",
  webpack: (config) => {
     config.output.publicPath = '/wp-content/themes/custom/out'
    }
(....)

Which outputs
https://localhost/custom.com/wp-content/themes/custom/out/rest/of/file.path

except for the bundled .json (blog.json, about.json etc).
The code for these file exists in the out/_next/static/chunks/main.js inside a function getDataHref(e) that is responsible for adding the base path to these json files. As of right now, I have to manually locate this section and change the path it's adding to the files.
The same is the case for just the .webm files in the /out/_next/static/media folder.
If this is a config issue please let me know, but I feel I've exhausted these options, I've tried modifying the getStaticProps and getStaticPaths options, with no success. The most success I've tried is to go after the main.js file and change that.
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const basePath = 'https://localhost/custom.com/wp-content/themes/custom/out/_next/static/chunks/';
function findMainFile() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(basePath);
  for (const file of files) {
    if (file.startsWith('main-')) {
      return path.join(basePath, file);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
function modifyFunction(filePath) {
  try {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    const newContent = fileContent.replace(
      'return (0, o.addBasePath)("/_next/data/" + this.buildId + t + p, !0)',
      'return (0, o.addBasePath)(" /wp-content/themes/custom/out/_next/data/" + this.buildId + t + p, !0)'
    );
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, newContent, 'utf8');
    console.log('Function modified successfully in:', filePath);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error modifying function:', error);
  }
}
const filePath = findMainFile();
if (filePath) {
  console.log('Found main file:', filePath);
  modifyFunction(filePath);
} else {
  console.error('Main file not found.');
}

The code I'm trying to modify custom/out/_next/static/chunks/main.js:
getDataHref(e) {
    let {
        asPath: t, href:n, locale:r
    }
    =e,
        {
        pathname: f, query:d, search:p
    }
    =(0, s.parseRelativeUrl)(n),
        {
        pathname: h
    }
    =(0, s.parseRelativeUrl)(t),
    m=(0, c.removeTrailingSlash)(f);
    if("/" !==m[0])throw Error('Route name should start with a "/", got "'+m+'"');
    return(e=> {
        let t=(0, l.default)((0, c.removeTrailingSlash)((0, i.addLocale)(e, r)), ".json");
        return(0, a.addBasePath)("/_next/data/"+this.buildId+t+p,  !0)
    }
    )(e.skipInterpolation?h:(0, u.isDynamicRoute)(m)?(0, o.interpolateAs)(f, h, d).result:m)
}

The basePath it has is /_next/data/ but it should be /wp-content/themes/custom/out/_next/data/.
Any help is much appreciated either in correcting the config or somehow forcing the final script.
Let me know if I can provide any more info.
